# Getting the average price of OPSkins pricelist via NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to somehow get the average price of every skin in [this list](https://files.opskins.media/file/opskins-static/pricelist/578080.json)

My question arises is how would one use the use dates and the prices to get the average price of 60 days?

In my idea I would parse the `JSON` for every item/object and get the dates and prices, then somehow loop through every date and add up the prices then divide by the days.

But I suppose my idea doesnt even need the dates but just the prices, though what difference does average and median give? Because I hear people use the word median for pricing rather than average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@jesusgn90](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2807174/jesusgn90) answer I figured it out and made it look like so:

```
const request = require("request");
var url = 'https://files.opskins.media/file/opskins-static/pricelist/578080.json';
request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, (err, res, body) => {
    if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
        var cur = new Date(),
            7daysbefore = cur.setDate(cur.getDate() - 7);
        var parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
        for (let item in parsed) {
            parsed[item]['average'] = 0;
            count = 0;
            for (date in parsed[item]) {
                if(new Date(date) >= cur){
                    parsed[item].average += parsed[item][date].price;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            parsed[item].average = Math.floor(parsed[item].average / count);
        }
    }
    fs.writeFile("test.json", JSON.stringify(parsed), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const minimumDate = getMinimumDate();

for(let item in list){
    let count  = 0;
    item['average'] = 0;
    for(let date in item){
         if(parse(date) >= minimumDate){
              item.average += date.price;
              count++;
         }
    }
    item.average /= count;
}
```

getMinimumDate is a function that gives you a date based on today less N days, in your case 60 days, implement it.

parse is a function that parse string to a date.

The median is the value in the middle of the highest and the minimum values in a sorted list.

The average it's the most common value.

1,1,1,2,3,4,6

The average is 18 / 7 = 2'....

There are 7 numbers, the median is the number in the position 7/2 + 1, so our median is 2 due to it is in 4th position.

If the list length is pair take two numbers add them and divide:

1,1,2,3,4,6

Take the two middles, 2+3 and divide by 2, so the median is 2.5